# How to calculate the length of a polynomial of degree 4 (within a square root)

Tags: bezier, integral, square-root

I am trying to solve an integral with this form (where a, b, c, d, e, f, and g are constants):

```
integral from f to g( (ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e)^0.5dx )
```

I've come across this when trying to find the length of a Cubic Bezier curve (without using recursive subdivision).  My goal is to have a symbolic equation that can find the length of a Bezier between any range of t (i.e f and g in the equation above).

My first guess was to complete the square, but Wikipedia was clear that that only works with quadratic equations.
Integration by parts... doesn't seem like it'd work for this.

The next question (though, not the subject of this topic), is using that really faster than recursively subdividing the Bezier?

Comment: I think this would work a bit better in math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I've done a little bit more research, and this site:
http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/curves/cbezarclen.html
Says:
_There is no closed-form solution, in general, to this integral for cubic polynomial curves_

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else finds this question, there is no closed form solution, but there are very efficient ways to find the length without doing recursive subdivision, such as described on http://pomax.github.com/bezierinfo/#arclength